# Hint for solving an indefinite integral

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I would like to solve the following integral
$$\int \frac{dx}{x^2 \sqrt[4]{(a-x^2)(b+x^2)}},$$
where $a$ and $b$ are the real constants.

**My attempt:** 
$$\sqrt[4]{(a-x^2)(b+x^2)} = \sqrt[4]{-\bigg[x^4 + (b-a)x^2 + (\frac{a-b}{2})^2\bigg]+(\frac{a+b}{2})^2} = \sqrt[4]{(\frac{a+b}{2})^2 - (x^2-\frac{a-b}{2})^2}$$

Substituting $t=x^2 - \frac{a-b}{2}$ one gets
$$\int \frac{dt}{2(t+ \frac{a-b}{2})^\frac{3}{2}\sqrt[4]{(\frac{a+b}{2})^2 - t^2}}$$ 
 I do not know what to do here!

Comment: Is there any reason you believe this integral should be expressible in terms of elementary functions? I don't believe it is.

Comment: I am afraid that Appell integrals would appear !

Comment: I agree with Claude Leibivici. This integral cannot be expressed with a finite number of elementary functions. The closed form involves a special function : Appell hypergeometric. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+dx%2F(x%5E2((a-x%5E2)(b%2Bx%5E2))%5E(1%2F4))&x=0&y=0